# Installing OpenCV and Extra modules on Windows 10 Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake-gui

I've been trying to install OpenCV extra modules to use the tracking algorithms. I have downloaded all the files and CMake by following this tutorial https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/

But however, I get to configuring in CMake-gui and I get an error I don't quite understand.

```
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    The C compiler identification is unknown
    Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
    CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_8cf7a.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"
    Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- broken
    CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:44 (message):
      The C++ compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
      14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

      It fails with the following output:

       Change Dir: C:/opencv-3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



      Run Build Command:"MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_8cf7a.vcxproj"
      "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"



      Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "MSBuild.exe"
      "cmTC_8cf7a.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"





      CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:127 (project)


    Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/opencv-3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/opencv-3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I don't quite understand what it means?
Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using OpenCV regularly with visual c++ 2015 and 2017.
I build OpenCV from the source directly without following the link you posted.
I suggest you clone OpenCV and OpenCV Extra Modules from git

You need the following tools: git, cmake (I'm using version 3.8.2), Visual C++ 2015 or Visual C++ 2017

```
cd projects
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
```

Open cmake to your `projects/opencv`, set the build directory, for example `build-vc140`, select Visual C++ 14 (for visual c++ 2015) or Visual C++ 15 (for visual c++ 2017) and run configure.
Set the path of `opencv_controlib/modules`, Set also the path where install the library setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

Generate, open the solution and build the `install` target

To include the library in your projects just set `OpenCV_DIR` to the installed path